# Is 2G the limit size of coredump file on Linux?

Tags: linux, gdb, archlinux, coredump

My OS is `Arch Linux`. When there is a coredump, I try to use gdb to debug it:

```
$ coredumpctl gdb 1621
......
       Storage: /var/lib/systemd/coredump/core.runTests.1014.b43166f4bba84bcba55e65ae9460beff.1621.1491901119000000000000.lz4
       Message: Process 1621 (runTests) of user 1014 dumped core.

                Stack trace of thread 1621:
                #0  0x00007ff1c0fcfa10 n/a (n/a)

GNU gdb (GDB) 7.12.1
......
Reading symbols from /home/xiaonan/Project/privDB/build/bin/runTests...done.
BFD: Warning: /var/tmp/coredump-28KzRc is truncated: expected core file size >= 2179375104, found: 2147483648.
```

I check the `/var/tmp/coredump-28KzRc` file:

```
$ ls -alth /var/tmp/coredump-28KzRc
-rw------- 1 xiaonan xiaonan 2.0G Apr 11 17:00 /var/tmp/coredump-28KzRc
```

Is `2G` the limit size of coredump file on Linux? Because I think my `/var/tmp` has enough disk space to use:

```
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
dev              32G     0   32G   0% /dev
run              32G  3.1M   32G   1% /run
/dev/sda2       229G   86G  132G  40% /
tmpfs            32G  708M   31G   3% /dev/shm
tmpfs            32G     0   32G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs            32G  957M   31G   3% /tmp
/dev/sda1       511M   33M  479M   7% /boot
/dev/sda3       651G  478G  141G  78% /home
```

P.S. "`ulimit -a`" outputs:

```
$ ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) unlimited
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 257039
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 257039
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Update: The `/etc/systemd/coredump.conf` file:

```
$ cat coredump.conf
#  This file is part of systemd.
#
#  systemd is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
#  under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by
#  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of the License, or
#  (at your option) any later version.
#
# Entries in this file show the compile time defaults.
# You can change settings by editing this file.
# Defaults can be restored by simply deleting this file.
#
# See coredump.conf(5) for details.

[Coredump]
#Storage=external
#Compress=yes
#ProcessSizeMax=2G
#ExternalSizeMax=2G
#JournalSizeMax=767M
#MaxUse=
#KeepFree=
```

Comment: Can you actually create a big enough file on your filesystem?

Comment: @SergeiKurenkov: yes, I use "`dd if=/dev/zero of=test bs=1024 count=4MB`" to create a `4G` file.

Comment: Here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768719/coredump-is-getting-truncated it is suggested to check also `ulimit -f`

Comment: Output all `ulimit`, seems no exception.

Comment: Look, there is no limit in gdb. This simple test program creates on my PC a 4GB core file: 

int main() { int *p = new int[1000000000]; int *q = nullptr; *q = *q +1; }

Comment: Can you show us your [coredump.conf](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/coredump.conf.html#) files?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick: `/etc/systemd/coredump.conf` doesn't configure anything.

Comment: Normally, a commented-out line in stock config files specifies the default. Try to uncomment and increase the value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@n.m. is correct.
(1) Modify `/etc/systemd/coredump.conf` file:

```
[Coredump]
ProcessSizeMax=8G
ExternalSizeMax=8G
JournalSizeMax=8G
```

(2) Reload systemd's configuration:

```
# systemctl daemon-reload
```

Notice this will only take effect for the new generated core dump files.

Answer (score 2):

> Is 2G the limit size of coredump file on Linux?

No. I routinely deal with core dumps larger than 4GiB.

> `ulimit -a`
>   `core file size          (blocks, -c) unlimited`

This tells you your *current* limit in this shell. It tells you *nothing* about the environment in which `runTests` ran. That process may be setting its own limit via `setrlimit(2)`, or its parent may be setting a limit for it.

You can modify runTest to print its current limit with `getrlimit(2)` and see what it actually is when the process runs.

P.S. Just because the `core` is truncated doesn't mean it's completely useless (though often it is). At a minimum, you should try the GDB `where` command.