# Limiting the core file size

Tags: linux, arm, coredump, setrlimit

I am trying to truncate the core file size for my application. I tried using `setrlimit()` function but had no luck.

Observations:
I set `rlim_cur = 270` which is `270 * 1024 = 276480 bytes`, and if the core file is less than `276480 bytes` only then the core file is getting generated. Core files with more than `276480 bytes` size are not generated. When I set `rlim_cur = RLIM_INFINITY` all core files are getting generated. Basically I am not able to truncate the file size to the required size. Please suggest.

Comment: What OS/platform/etc.?

Comment: Linux on arm platform.

Comment: I've added the missing tags. In future it would be great if you could include them straight away. Anyway, I suspect this might be better suited to the Unix/Linux sister site, as it doesn't seem to be about programming as such.

Comment: @klekle please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: sure i ll include the tags in future.

Answer (score -1):

Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768719/coredump-is-getting-truncated) and [this](https://kb.netapp.com/support/s/article/ka31A0000000vCiQAI/how-to-remove-a-core-file-size-restriction?language=en_US), these linkes explain about hard and soft limits and `ulimit` command

Comment: I tried changing the rlim_cur and rlim_max values, I observed that the core file will get generated only if the core file size is less than the rlim_cur & rlim_max value. I want it to truncate to required size which i am unable to achieve. I tried changing soft and hard values in /etc/security/limit.conf as well, seems to be not working. How do i truncate it to 200MB?